# Working with google map in android

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I want to work on `google maps`
tried to get help from [this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/) but i cant see `google` play service on extra folder
i updated my `sdk` to 23, but nothing changed and not working.

When i want to update, this error occur :

```
Unable to read repository at https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/.
Unable to read repository at https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/.
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ is not a valid repository location.
```

What should i do?
Thanks!

Comment: Is your system running behind a proxy server? If yes then you need to add the proxy settings to the sdk manager under Tools->Options

Comment: yes im using, added my proxy information to where you mentioned, but nothing change, do i missing some setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below steps to solve your issue :

1 - Open your eclipse

2 - Go to menu Help->Install new software

3 - Click on Add

4 -  In location please put : http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ [Do not use http**s** , Use http]

5 - Click on OK and you will able to install your desired things.

Let me know if any confusion there.

Comment: thanks, following errors occured: Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.
"Android DDMS" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android Traceview" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android Hierarchy Viewer" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android Development Tools" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Tracer for OpenGL ES" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android Native Development Tools" will be ignored because it is already installed.

Comment: i unchecked mentioned package, then it says above error for other package, actually it saying all package are install, but i cant see google play service in extra folder :(

Comment: It looks your packages are not installed proper first time. Please remove your android SKD folder totally and then use this way to install from begin. Because even if it get single file of any tool and it consider that is installed already. I have also experienced this issue in past.

Comment: i downloaded the sdk and eclipse both in a zip folder  from google, so dont think my problem is the sdk, btw im using tor proxy, is for that?

Comment: i tried to start eclipse throw the tor proxy by using this command: sudo torify ./eclipse, but following error occured in sdk manager: Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: HttpHostConnect Connection to https://dl-ssl.google.com refused

Comment: Have you set any proxy setting? in eclipse?

Comment: yes, added to sdk manager, Tools->Options, and nothing more, do i missing something?

Comment: means? I did not get you in your last message.

Comment: i went to SDK manger -> Tools -> Options and set the Http proxy server to 127.0.0.1 and and Http proxy port to 9050, but didnt again...

Comment: why you using proxy? any reason? also remove proxy until you install all android package. then you can set again for your purpose.

Comment: without proxy i cant set code.google or developer.google

Comment: As I told you please remove proxy setting until you complete setup of sdk.

Comment: i did it but nothing changed, but as i mentioned, links like code.google.com, developer.google.com are not reachable without proxy for me

Comment: in my country, some google services are forbidden so i have to use sth like tor proxy, how can i solve my problem now?

Comment: that problem was in linux(ubuntu),  in windows there is no problem and installed easily, i dont know why.